# optional update statements in diesel using into_boxed()

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

When I run below code it compiles but it won't update any `todo` item and affected_rows is equal to 0. What I'm doing wrong here?

Note: I checked official [documentation](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/query_builder/struct.UpdateStatement.html#example-1) and I didn't find any solution...

```rust
pub fn update_todo(req_id: i32, update_payload: TodoUpdate) -> Result<usize, Error> 
{
    let connection = establish_connection();

    let title_payload = match update_payload.title {
        Some(title_payload)=> title_payload,
        None => "".to_string()
    };

    let status_payload = match update_payload.status {
        Some(status_payload)=> status_payload,
        None => "".to_string()
    };

    let mut query = update(todos)
        .set(id.eq(req_id)).into_boxed();

    if title_payload.len() > 5 {
        query = query.filter(title.eq(title_payload));
    }

    if status_payload.len() > 3 {
        query = query.filter(status.eq(status_payload));
    }

    query.execute(&connection)
}
```

Note2: It works fine when I don't use `into_boxed()` and removing if statements. but I want to work if only title length is greater than 5 and status length greater than 3. It's why I used `into_boxed` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I was doing the whole thing wrong and the right concept is to use `AsChangeset` in order to update `rows` in database;

For any one reading this:

The right approach is to use an `Option` in your structs and `derive` the `AsChangeset` alongside `table_name` like below example:

**In this example we have a `todo` row and we only want to change/update the title of our `todo` but not changing the status**

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, AsChangeset)]
#[table_name="todos"]
pub struct  TodoUpdate {
    pub title: Option<String>,
    pub status: Option<String>
}
```

Now we have to fix handler and add validations! I use `match` statement to check if there's a value or not and if there was a value inside `title` I check for it's length otherwise I just ignore it. for example:

```rust
match update_payload.title {
    Some(ref title_req) => if title_req.len() < 3 {
        return HttpResponse::BadRequest().json(json!({
            "result": false,
            "message": "Title should be at least 3 letter"
        }));
    },
    None => (),
};

match update_payload.status {
    Some(ref status_req) => if status_req.len() < 3 {
        return HttpResponse::BadRequest().json(json!({
            "result": false,
            "message": "Status should be at least 3 letter"
        }));
    },
    None => (),
};
```

After all I call the service I made for updating `todos` and it's very simple.

```rust
pub fn update_todo(req_id: i32, update_payload: TodoUpdate) -> Result<usize, Error> 
{
    let connection = establish_connection();


    diesel::update(todos.filter(id.eq(req_id)))
        .set::<TodoUpdate>(update_payload)
        .execute(&connection)
}
```

whew!!! and these codes works fine.. I hope this was helpful for you all.

PS: if you really want to validate user request data you can use [actix-web-validator](https://github.com/rambler-digital-solutions/actix-web-validator)